# Ubercart Marketplace seller own orders empty

Tags: drupal, ubercart, marketplace

x-2.11 and Ubercart Marketplace 6.x-1.0-beta1. Everythings work but sellers can't see their own orders. I searched solution but i can't find. I was read it maybe about condutional settings. Still i have not a solution. What i must set condutional settings? Or what it's solution? Thanks.